# How to create a desktop-entry for anaconda on Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: anaconda

I've recently installed anaconda3 in Ubuntu 17.10 (system environment). To run anaconda-navigator, I've to activate root for each time as

```
Source ~/anaconda3/bin/activate root
```

And to run it I've to write each time

```
anaconda-navigator
```

Now I am wanted to create a desktop entry but I'm having errors at multiple stages. Can you please explain from beginning how to create a desktop-entry for anaconda3 on Linux?

EDIT: I've tried using this post [on AskUbuntu.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1017284/cant-create-anaconda-shortcut-to-launch-from-desktop-on-ubuntu-17-10/1062504#1062504) But, it failed for me. It is not showing on dock-bar as well as in `/usr/share/applications`. I'm really frustrated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, check if anaconda3 is installed on your system or not (Sometime the package may be broken due to network issues during installation (Not worked for me)). And whether you are able to launch `anaconda-navigator` without a desktop entry.

### For creating a desktop entry

**Step 1.** Open your text editor and save the following content as `Anaconda.desktop` to your home directory.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Anaconda-Navigator
GenericName=Anaconda
Comment=Scientific Python Development Environment - Python3
Exec='$HOME/anaconda3/bin/anaconda-navigator'
Categories=Development;Science;IDE;Qt;Education;
Icon=$HOME/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/static/images/anaconda-icon-256x256.png
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true
MimeType=text/x-python;
```

Take care with the Python version. in `$HOME/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/static/images/anaconda-icon-256x256.png` change `python3.8` if needed

**Step 2.** Copy your `Anaconda.desktop` to `/usr/share/applications/` as root (Because you might need permission to copy at /usr/share/applications/)
sudo cp Anaconda.desktop /usr/share/applications
This will create a desktop entry named `Anaconda` in `/usr/share/applications/`.

**Step 3.** add this line `export PATH="$HOME/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"` to your `/etc/profile` or `$HOME/.bashrc`

**Step 4.** Check if `Anaconda` is added to your application dock. If you didn't find it, search it in search-bar. Or you can run directly from `/usr/share/applications/Anaconda.desktop`.

Comment: Creating a desktop entry may be sometimes tricky in other Linux distributions.

Comment: There might also be some trouble in installation of anaconda that does not leads to a desktop entry in dock.

Comment: You can also test that.

Comment: This is also doable.